# org-mode babel progress indicator?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

When I run a process in the Mac Terminal, it gives me an indication of its progress. Here we see that I am 31% complete on downloading the latest org-mode:

[image]

How can I get this same sort of progress indicator, when running a process from within a code block in org-mode?

Comment: I guess this is not possible in general. You would have to know in advance how much work needs to be done, and at some point in time how much work has been done.

Comment: Well, somehow Terminal figures this out. Emacs can run shell commands, so I have to believe there is someway to implement a similar type of indicator in Emacs... This would especially be useful for scientific computing (i.e, processing large datasets in R) so that you know the process is actually working and not stalled or frozen.

Comment: See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21747/emms-how-can-i-have-a-progress-bar. The example you show can work because you know how many objects to receive, and how many have been received. If you don't know how long a src block should take, there is now way to know how much progress has been made.

Comment: I don't know about R, but in Python, we have set up an asynchronous way of running it where you can see intermediate output in another buffer. See https://github.com/jkitchin/scimax/blob/master/scimax-org-babel-python.el for how that is done.

Comment: I am not sure but maybe [ob-async](https://github.com/astahlman/ob-async) helps?

Comment: I've tried ob-async. Pitingly it does not help for your purpose. Org-babel does not output results asynchronously but puts in a preplacement-id until the job is finished.